# Programmatically sharing a file in a Teamdrive with a specific user (who is not a member of the Teamdrive)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to share a specific file with a specific user using a Google Apps Script. The file is in a Teamdrive, the user it not a member of the Teamdrive and should not be a member of the Teamdrive.

As far as I know, the way to do this in normal Drives with DriveApp doesn't work in Teamdrives, so I'm trying to use the Drive REST API. As I understand it, the syntax to do this is:

```
  Drive.Permissions.insert(
    {role: "reader",
     type: "user",
     value: USER_EMAIL
    },
    FILE_ID,
    {sendNotificationEmails:false,
     supportsTeamDrives:true,
     useDomainAdminAccess:true
    }
  )
```

This results in an error message that reads:

> API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Team Drive not found: FILE_ID

When I replaced the FILE_ID with the ID for the Teamdrive, it set the user as a member of the whole Teamdrive.

How do I specify which file to set permissions for, or more generally, how can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Seems possible from the UI (https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/sharing-best-practices/#!/section-4-3). Can you clarify if the file to be shared is in the root of the Team Drive, or is in a child folder of the Team Drive?

Comment: The file I was using to test was at the root, but eventually I want it to work on files in child folders. I can use the UI to do exactly what I want manually, but I'm looking for a script solution.

Comment: Have you tried your code above with the item in a subfolder of the root? It would be good to clarify the locations you have tested. Also, to be clear, the account you are executing this code with, the file is accessible to it? (I would think so, due to the domain admin access, but good to check). Have you checked the `capabilities` of this file (i.e., call  `files.get` on it)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of TeamDrive is so that you cannot just share out the information, you can see it but it doesn't belong to you. You might be able to use a script to copy it to your own drive and share that?

Comment: That's not true, as in a shared drive you are able to upload files and share them with people outside of the team. You can't share entire directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but when I added the `supportsTeamDrives:true` argument it worked. It [should be deprecated](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert) on June 1, 2020.
So command now looks like this:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
      {
        value,
        type,
        role,
        withLink: false
      },
      fileId,
      {
        sendNotificationEmails: false,
        supportsAllDrives: true
      });
```